# Does histogram equalization change the pixel intensity range? (16-bit)

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, histogram-equalization

Currently, I am doing histogram equalization on a 16 bit image, would the range change from [0, 65536] after the process?

```
import numpy as np
hist, bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(), 65536, [0, 65536])  # Collect 16 bits histogram (65536 = 2^16)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? I think `np.histogram` is certainly not the most suited function here. Consider looking [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) (it should be faster and guarantee the size of the output)

Answer (score 0):

The range of pixel intensities would stay [0, 65536] due to the weight factor of 65536 in the transform map. More details in link below.

```
transform_map = np.floor(65536* chistogram_array).astype(np.uint8)
```

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/introduction-to-histogram-equalization-for-digital-image-enhancement-420696db9e43